# Skybox is fully Black

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, skybox

I am new at openGL

I created this skybox on  LWJGL but It's all black

SkyboxRenderer Class :

```
private static String[] TEXTURE_FILES = {"right","left","bottom","back","front"};
private RawModel cube;
private int texture;
private SkyboxShader shader;

public SkyboxRenderer(Loader loader, Matrix4f projectionMatirx) {
    cube = loader.loadToVAO(VERTICES, 3);
    texture = loader.loadCubeMap(TEXTURE_FILES);
    shader = new SkyboxShader();
    shader.start();
    shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatirx);
    shader.stop();
}

public void render(Camera camera){
    shader.start();
    shader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(cube.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, cube.getVertexCount());
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    shader.stop();
}
```

Loader loadCubeMap function :

```
public int loadCubeMap(String[] textureFiles){
    int texID = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texID);

    for(int i = 0; i < textureFiles.length;i++){
        TextureData data = decodeTextureFile("res/" + textureFiles[i] + ".png");
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, data.getWidth(), data.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, 
                GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.getBuffer());

    }
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    textures.add(texID);
    return texID;
}

private TextureData decodeTextureFile(String fileName) {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    ByteBuffer buffer = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);
        width = decoder.getWidth();
        height = decoder.getHeight();
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * width * height);
        decoder.decode(buffer, width * 4, Format.RGBA);
        buffer.flip();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Tried to load texture " + fileName + ", didn't work");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return new TextureData(buffer, width, height);
}
```

Textures exist, but skybox is fullyblack can someone help me!
How can i fix it

I need to add more details for posting because there is too  much code...

SkyboxShader :

public class SkyboxShader extends ShaderProgram{

```
private static final String VERTEX_FILE = "src/com/redcatengine/skybox/skyboxVertexShader.txt";
private static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = "src/com/redcatengine/skybox/skyboxFragmentShader.txt";

private int location_projectionMatrix;
private int location_viewMatrix;

public SkyboxShader() {
    super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
}

public void loadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f matrix){
    super.loadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, matrix);
}

public void loadViewMatrix(Camera camera){
    Matrix4f matrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
    matrix.m30 = 0;
    matrix.m31 = 0;
    matrix.m32 = 0;
    super.loadMatrix(location_viewMatrix, matrix);
}

@Override
protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
    location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
    location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
}

@Override
protected void bindAttributes() {
    super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
}
```

}

public abstract class ShaderProgram {

```
private int programID;
private int vertexShaderID;
private int fragmentShaderID;

private static FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
public ShaderProgram(String vertexFile, String fragmentFile) {
    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    bindAttributes();
    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    getAllUniformLocations();
}

protected abstract void getAllUniformLocations();

protected int getUniformLocation(String uniformName){
    return GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, uniformName); 
}

public void start(){
    GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
}

public void stop(){
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}

public void cleanUp(){
    stop();
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
}

protected abstract void bindAttributes();

protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String variableName){
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
}

protected void loadInt(int location, int value){
    GL20.glUniform1i(location, value);
}


protected void loadFloat(int location, float value){
    GL20.glUniform1f(location, value);
}

protected void loadVector(int location, Vector3f value){
    GL20.glUniform3f(location, value.x, value.y, value.z);
}

protected void load2DVector(int location, Vector2f value){
    GL20.glUniform2f(location, value.x, value.y);
}

protected void loadBoolean(int location, boolean value){
    float toLoad = 0;
    if(value)toLoad = 1;else toLoad = 0;
    GL20.glUniform1f(location, toLoad);
}

protected void loadMatrix(int location, Matrix4f matrix){
    matrix.store(matrixBuffer);
    matrixBuffer.flip();
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4(location, false, matrixBuffer);
}

private static int loadShader(String file, int type){
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Could not read shader file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)==GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
        System.out.println("Could not compile shader.");
        System.exit(-1);    
    }
    return shaderID;
}
```

}

skyboxFragmentShader :

```
#version 400

in vec3 textureCoords;
out vec4 out_Color;

uniform samplerCube cubeMap;

void main(void){
    out_Color = texture(cubeMap, textureCoords);
}
```

skyboxVertexShader

```
#version 400

in vec3 position;
out vec3 textureCoords;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); 
    textureCoords = position;

}`
```

Comment: what's your skybox shader code looking like?

Comment: @derhass I add it to question post other shaders works pefectly

Comment: Are the textures you're loading for the cube map square?

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes textures are 1024x1024

Comment: @KodeKishin: You still have not included the actual source code of the shader files. The fact that other shaders work is not really helpful for this question. Your skybox shader needs to correctly sample a cube map texture, and it is totally unclear if it does that or not.

Comment: @derhass thanks for helping, i added others too do you know why skybox is black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cube map texture is not *cube complete*:

Your loader code iterates over all files in the array it is called with:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < textureFiles.length;i++){
>     // [...]
>     GL11.glTexImage2D(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, [...])
> }
> ```

However, your input array contains only **5** entires:

> ```
> String[] TEXTURE_FILES = {"right","left","bottom","back","front"};
> ```

You provide only 5 faces for the cube, and forgot the "top" face.

According to the GL spec (quotes are from section 8.17 of the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf)),

> A cube map texture is mipmap complete if each of the six texture
>   images, considered individually, is mipmap complete. **Additionally, a
>   cube map texture is cube complete if the following conditions all hold
>   true:**
>
> - The level_base texture images of **each of the six cube map faces have identical, positive, and square dimensions.**
> - The levelbase
>     images were each specified with the same internal format.

It further goes on define *texture completeness*:

> Using the preceding definitions, a texture is complete unless any of the following
>   conditions hold true:
>
> - [...]
> - The texture is a cube map texture, and is not cube complete.
> - [...]

So your cube map texture is not *complete*.

Section 11.1.3.5 states:

> If a sampler is used in a shader and the sampler’s associated texture is not
>   complete, as defined in section 8.17, `(0; 0; 0; 1)` will be returned for a non-shadow sampler and `0` for a shadow sampler.

So indeed, your cube map should appear completely black.

Comment: Thank you so much :D @derhass